.net maui Play app signing The private key was not properly encrypted, or is not a type of key we support
I'm trying to publish a .net Maui Android app to the Play Store. I have previously published it as an apk file signed with a local keystore, no problem, when it was Xamarin and I was using VS Mac. Now I've migrated to MAUI and I'm trying to publish it as a bundle (.aab) instead, and the Play Console is requiring "Play app signing."
In Visual Studio, I tried Importing the keystore file I previously used to sign the apk file, but whereas in previous versions of Visual Studio with Xamarin it only asked for a password and now it's asking for an alias, a password, and a key password, so I suspect it's a different format? So I just created a new keystore file instead.
In the Google Play Console, on the App Signing page, I'm following the instructions carefully under "Let Google Play manager your app signing key."
After I download the public key, download the PEPK tool, I run this command.
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23.0.1\bin\java"  -jar pepk.jar --keystore=appname.keystore --alias=appnamealias --output=encrypted_private_key.pem --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem

It asks for my passwords for the store and the key, and generates the file encrypted_private_key.pem.
I click "Upload private key," select the encrypted_private_key.pem file that it generated, and I get the error message, "The private key was not properly encrypted, or is not a type of key we support."
I have tried different versions of the JDK, and every suggestion posted to other related posts.  The only thing I can think of is that this is an app signed with a different keystore as an apk, so is it failing because of that?  If so, how can I get Visual Studio to import the previous Keystore file that worked on the apk when I published it with Xamarin?

I'm making some progress importing my original keystore... using the keytool I found that I was using the wrong alias. And it told me It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystorename.keystore -destkeystore newkeystorename.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".

The problem appears to be that I wasn't using the same keystore as previous versions of the app. I ran keytool -list on it to make sure I was using the correct alias, which I wasn't, and that recommend to migrate it to PKCS12 by using the command:
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystorename.keystore -destkeystore newkeystorename.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
That migrated version imported into Visual Studio without errors, and worked in the Play Console's Play App Signing page.
